# How to fix when trying to add data values to a listbox from another form

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, telnet

I am having an issue while trying to add data to a listbox from my main form, I am trying to add data to that list from a new class in my project, I need that new class to be able to add data to my listbox without errors, I am trying to use a invoke and I am getting the following error (System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.') I have seen that error in other questions in stack overflow but similar to my issue, I will be adding both classes of my code here, one is the main class and the other a second class I created that will need to add data to the listbox. the data is coming from a telnet tcp/ip and port 23 that connection is working fine, the problem is adding that data to my listbox.

Main class calling the functions from my other class

namespace BarcodeReceivingApp
{

```
//TelnetConnection stopConnection = new TelnetConnection();
public partial class BarcodeReceivingForm : Form
{
    //GLOBAL VARIABLES
    const string Hostname = "myip";
    private const int Port = 23;


    public BarcodeReceivingForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_ConnectT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var readData = new TelnetConnection(Hostname, Port);
        readData.ServerSocket(Hostname, Port);

    }

    private void btn_StopConnection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //var connection = new TelnetConnection(Hostname, Port);
       // connection.CloseConnection();
    }
}
```

}

class that will change the data of my listbox from the main class.

```
 namespace BarcodeReceivingApp
```

{
    public class TelnetConnection
    {
        public BarcodeReceivingForm BcForm = new BarcodeReceivingForm();

```
    private Thread _readWriteThread;
    private TcpClient _client;
    private NetworkStream _networkStream;
    private string _hostname;
    private int _port;

    public TelnetConnection(string hostname, int port)
    {
        this._hostname = hostname;
        this._port = port;
    }

    public void ServerSocket(string ip, int port)
    {

        try
        {
            _client = new TcpClient(ip, port);         
        }
        catch (SocketException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"Failed to connect to server");
            return;
        }

        //Assign networkstream
        _networkStream = _client.GetStream();

        //start socket read/write thread
        _readWriteThread = new Thread(ReadWrite);
        _readWriteThread.Start();
    }

    public void ReadWrite()
    {

        //Set up connection loop
        while (true)
        {
            var command = "test";
            if (command == "STOP1")
                break;

            //write(command);
             var received = Read();


            BcForm.lst_BarcodeScan.Invoke(new Action (() => BcForm.lst_BarcodeScan.Items.Add(received)));


        }

    }

    public string Read()
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        var received = "";

        var size = _networkStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        received = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, size);

        return received;
    }

    public void CloseConnection()
    {
        _networkStream.Close();
        _client.Close();
    }
}
}
```

the final results like I said is my ReadWrite method when running the loop will add the data to my listbox from my main form class

here the image where I get the error 
[Image of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfOSs.png)

Comment: You would have to show the form using `BcForm.Show()` before using invoke.

Comment: Or you can simply use it like this `BcForm.lst_BarcodeScan.Items.Add(received);
`

Comment: I tried that but it's bringing a new form and I don't want that I just want my normal class to add data to my list automatically without creating a new form from the main form, hope that makes sense?

Comment: I also tried the BcForm.lst_BarcodeScan.Items.Add(received); but all I get is blank list no input data from the telnet port, if I make my readwrite method in the main class it works but I want to put all my methods in a separate class and call those functions from the main class is when I get that error and I cant enter data to my listbox

Comment: Then simply use `BarcodeReceivingForm.lst_BarcodeScan.Items.Add(received)`;

Comment: adding BarcodeReceivingForm.lst_BarcodeScan.Items.Add(received); is basically the same as using the BcForm.lst_BarcodeScan.Items.Add(received); same issue for some reason the my while loop is not adding that data from my separate class, but like I said if I put that function in the main class the it works add the data without any issues, but I want to be able to do the same from a separate class

Comment: They are not the same. Try it first and see. Using BcForm creates a New instance of the form.

Comment: I tried and when trying to add BarcodeReceivingForm.lst_BarcodeScan in my loop and it won't list the listbox to select it

Comment: I have added an answer, try it and get back to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your second class like this

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms; 
namespace BarcodeReceivingApp { 
    public class TelnetConnection { 

        private Thread _readWriteThread;
        private TcpClient _client;
        private NetworkStream _networkStream;
        private string _hostname;
        private int _port;
        private Form foo;

        public TelnetConnection(string hostname, int port)
        {
            this._hostname = hostname;
            this._port = port;
        }

        public void ServerSocket(string ip, int port,Form f)
        {
            this.foo = f;
            try
            {
                _client = new TcpClient(ip, port);         
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(@"Failed to connect to server");
                return;
            }

            _networkStream = _client.GetStream();

            _readWriteThread = new Thread(ReadWrite());
            _readWriteThread.Start();
        }  

        public void ReadWrite()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var command = "test";
                if (command == "STOP1")
                    break;

                //write(command);
                 var received = Read();
                 if (foo.lst_BarcodeScan.InvokeRequired)
                 {
                         foo.lst_BarcodeScan.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {foo.lst_BarcodeScan.Items.Add(received);}));
                 }
            }
        }

        public string Read()
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            var received = "";

            var size = _networkStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            received = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, size);

            return received;
        }

        public void CloseConnection()
        {
            _networkStream.Close();
            _client.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like this from your main class:

```
private void btn_ConnectT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var readData = new TelnetConnection(Hostname, Port);
    readData.ServerSocket(Hostname, Port, this);

}
```

Comment: thanks, but I am getting a line error here `_readWriteThread = new Thread(ReadWrite(f));` it says (cannot convert from void to system.threading.threadingStart)

Comment: I made that change, and now I am getting this error `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'lst_BarcodeScan' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.'` on line code `_readWriteThread = new Thread(ReadWrite());` now I am using the `private BarcodeReceivingForm foo`; not `private Form foo;` because BarcodeReceivingForm  is what have the access to the listbox

Comment: thanks man that worked now display data to the listbox without any errors, thanks buddy  you are a good coder.

Comment: Please Mark the answer by ticking the Mark to the left of this answer. You are welcome!